# Error in update query

Tags: postgresql

I have two entities STOCK(name,amount) and PC_SYSTEMS(name,c_name), and i wish to update the components needed to create the PC_system "Alienware", therefore i want it to subtract 1 from the amount of the components, needed to create the alienware system, in Stock.

Here's my query:

```
"UPDATE stock SET amount=amount-1 WHERE name = ( SELECT p.c_name FROM pc_systems p WHERE p.name='Alienware');"
```

I get a weird error that says:

" more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Would be happy if someone could help.

Edit:

I SOLVED this by putting an "IN" in my query instead of "=". Final code:

```
UPDATE stock SET amount=amount-1 WHERE name IN ( SELECT p.c_name FROM pc_systems p        WHERE p.name='Alienware');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your subquery is returning more than one record you cannot use that syntax. try something like this:

```
UPDATE S
SET S.amount=S.amount-1
FROM Stock S
INNER JOIN pc_systems p
    ON S.name = p.c_name
WHERE p.name='Alienware'
```

or try this:

```
update stock 
set s.amount=s.amount-1
from stock s
inner join pc_systems p on S.name = p.c_name
where p.name='Alienware'
```

Comment: i tried this, but it said that relation 's' doesnt exist. this doesnt look like the standard notation tho, usually its like UPDATE <table> SET <attribute> = ... :)

Comment: got the error " column reference "amount" is ambiguous
LINE 2: set amount=amount-1". trying to find out what may be the error.

Comment: @John you just need to add the alias to the start of amount. I edited my answer.

Comment: believe it or not, but i get the same error which i got when I typed in the first query

Comment: i SOLVED this by putting an "IN" into my previous code instead of "=".. i wish i had known lol.

Answer (score 3):

What it means is this SQL returns more than 1 row.  Make it so it returns exactly 1 row only.

```
SELECT p.c_name FROM pc_systems p WHERE p.name='Alienware'
```

Comment: this doesn't update the amount of components needed for alienware in stock, but i see your point